# 0.0 Accuracy when using KNN on extracted text features by camemBERT

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, nlp, bert-language-model

I'm trying to use camembert model to just to extract text features. After that, I'm trying to use a KNN classifier to classify the feature vectors as inputs.

This is the code I wrote

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, CamembertModel
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import torch

# Initialize the Camembert tokenizer and model
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("camembert-base")
model = CamembertModel.from_pretrained("camembert-base")

# Select the relevant columns from the DataFrame
cols = ["Intitulé (Ce champ doit respecter la nomenclature suivante : Code action – Libellé)_y", "Domaine sou domaine "]
df = df[cols]

# Convert DataFrame to a dictionary with row indices as keys and cell values as values
data = df.to_dict(orient='split')
data = dict(zip(data['index'], data['data']))

# Collect all the input texts into a list of strings
input_texts = [str(text) for text in data.values()]

# Set the batch size for processing
batch_size = 8

# Initialize lists to store the input features and labels
input_features_list = []
input_labels_list = []

# Process the data in batches
for i in range(0, len(input_texts), batch_size):
    batch_texts = input_texts[i:i + batch_size]

    # Tokenize the batch of texts
    inputs = tokenizer(batch_texts, return_tensors="pt", padding=True, truncation=True)

    # Get the model outputs for the batch
    with torch.no_grad():
        outputs = model(**inputs)

    # Extract the last hidden states and convert them to a numpy array
    last_hidden_states = outputs.last_hidden_state
    input_features = last_hidden_states[:, 0, :].numpy()

    # Add the input features and labels to the corresponding lists
    input_features_list.append(input_features)
    input_labels_list.extend(list(data.keys())[i:i + batch_size])

# Concatenate the input features and labels for all batches
input_features = np.concatenate(input_features_list)
input_labels = input_labels_list

# Split the data into training and testing sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(input_features, input_labels, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Initialize and train the KNeighborsClassifier
neigh = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3)
neigh.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Make predictions on the testing data
y_pred = neigh.predict(X_test)

# Calculate the accuracy
accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)

print("Accuracy:", accuracy)
```

The data I'm using in the dictionary has this form:

```
{
    'index': [row_index_1, row_index_2, ...],
    'columns': [column_name_1, column_name_2, ...],
    'data': [
        [cell_value_row_1_col_1, cell_value_row_1_col_2, ...],
        [cell_value_row_2_col_1, cell_value_row_2_col_2, ...],
        ...
    ]
}
```

When executing the code, it runs for 70 minutes then I get 0.0 Accuracy. Please let me know if want me to provide more details.

Comment: An accuracy of 0% always makes me suspicious because even with random data, you should guess a single one correctly now and then. Are you sure that the model is returning the labels in the correct format, the same as your y_test? 

Maybe start with simplifying your problem only using 2 classes instead of 65 labels. This way you can already test if your script is working properly.

Comment: @Simi I'm 100% sure I made a mistake when implementing the model and there is nothing wrong with the data itself. 
As for you what you said, I'm splitting the y_train and y_test AFTER tokenizing them so could that be the problem?

Comment: If the input features is a 2D list, list of the embeddings and the input_labels is a list of elements, it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: I don't think it will make a difference but you are using .append(input_features) and later on np.concatenate() to flatten again. Can you not just use .extend() again?

Comment: Pls `print(y_pred)` and `print(y_test)`

Comment: The bounty attracted several [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) plagiarisers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how big is your dataset and how many labels do you have. If you have a big test set and few labels this is really strange.

Another suggestion I can give you is to use sentence BERT (https://www.sbert.net/) which should be better for this kind of task. I would also consider to use SetFit to fine tune the embeddings even with few examples. Hope this helps :)

Comment: The dataset has 44k rows and I'm working with 65 labels

Comment: Which is the language you are working on? Is it a single label classification?

Comment: You have many labels, I wouldn't use CamemBERT which is not trained to produce good embeddings. You can try to plot the test set with the color indicating the label and you'll probably see that this model can not clusters your classes. I suggest you to use SetFit, to fine tune the sentence bert embeddings on your dataset and then train a classifier on top of that. Otherwise, also train a tf-idf model from your dataset and train a classifier on top could be better than your current approach. Try also other classifiers, because k-NN requires good embeddings

Comment: thank you for your answer. I'm using camemBERT mainly because I'm working with the French language and I didn't find any other good models in French

Comment: Camembert is indeed not the best model if you want to compute semantic similarity using a distance metric. You can replace the Camembert model with the multilingual e5 model https://huggingface.co/intfloat/multilingual-e5-base. 

Of course, evaluate the results on your testset to finally determine what works best.